# Elegant way to retry blocks in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

Smalltalk supports retry exceptions by using on: retry method defining the behavior between retries. I want to implement retry behaviors consisting of two additional operations: delayInterval, maxAttempts

```
[ operations ]
on: Exception
maxAttempts: 10
delayInterval: 5 seconds
do: [ : e | Transcript show: 'Trying...'; cr ]
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You want the block after `do:` to execute before each retry? Like, operations, delay, do, operations, delay, do, ...?

Comment: Which Smalltalk dialects are you targeting?

Comment: Any dialect would be fine

Answer (score 5):

Carlos's approach is fine, but the problem I see with it is that sends the `#on:do:` message a number of times. This is not necessary thanks to the fact that `Exceptions` understand the `#retry` message. So, instead of enclosing everything in a loop, we can loop inside the handling block, like this:

```
BlockClosure >> on: aClass do: aBlock maxAttempts: anInteger
  | counter |
  counter := anInteger.
  ^self
    on: aClass
    do: [:ex | | result |
      result := aBlock value: ex.
      counter := counter - 1.
      counter > 0 ifTrue:[ex retry].
      ex return: result]
```

Note that there is no "syntactic" loop in this code. The flow of execution, however, will evaluate the receiving block again in virtue of the `ex retry` message (without reaching the `ex return: result` line). Only if the `counter` reaches `0` the handler will "give up" and return the value of the exception block `aBlock`.

This same idea can now be used to introduce a timeout:

```
on: aClass
do: aBlock
maxAttempts: anInteger
timeout: anotherInteger
  | counter timeout |
  counter := anInteger.
  timeout := TimeStamp now asMilliseconds + anotherInteger "dialect dependent".
  ^self
    on: aClass
    do: [:ex | | result |
      result := aBlock value: ex.
      counter := counter - 1.
      (counter > 0 and: [TimeStamp now asMilliseconds < timeout])
         ifTrue: [ex retry].
      ex return: result]
```

The same considerations apply here. The only difference is that the `retry` condition also takes into account the timeout limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
on: exceptionClass maxAttempts: anInteger delayInterval: seconds do: aBlock

max := anInteger.
exception := false.
[ result := self on: exceptionClass do: [ :ex | aBlock value: ex. exception := true. max := max - 1 ].
exception and: [max > 0 ] ] whileTrue: [ exception := false ].
^result
```

"elegant" is arguable...